# How to fetch text file data in a variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling, filehandle

In python how we can select second line string of a text file.

I have a text file and in that file there are some data in line by line_

```
Dog
Cat
Cow
```

How to fetch the second line which is “Cat” and store that string in a variable.

```
f = open(“text_file.txt”, “r”)
var =    # “Cat”
```

Can I use single line code without using any loop or anything like we open a file using this single line of code `f = open(“text_file.txt”, “r”)`

Comment: `var = f.readlines()[1]`

Comment: Sir when i run this code f = open("cred.txt", "r")

apikey = f.readlines()[1]
client_token = f.readlines()[2]
password = f.readlines()[3]
print(apikey)
print(client_token)
print(password) i'm getting error like this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nayan\PycharmProjects\Angel_Broking\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    client_token = f.readlines()[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: index 1 not 2 mean can you please elaborate sir i can't understand

Comment: You asked for a 1-line solution to get the 2nd line. `readlines()[1]` will give you the *2nd* line of the file, not the 1st: `readlines()[0]` will give you the 1st. But now it appears you wanted to get several lines from the file, not just one. That can't be done in a single line because you can only call `readlines()` once on an open file. The first time reads all of the lines in the file and gives you back a list of them. That uses the lines up, and calling `readlines()` again will give you an empty list. So: `mylist = f.readlines(); apikey=mylist[0]; client_token=mylist[1]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following

```
with open('anim.txt','r') as f:
    var = f.readlines()[1].strip()

print(var)
```

- `[1]` get the second line
- `.strip()` removes the new line character from the end of the string
- `with open...` safely opens/closes the file

Answer (score 1):

Open your file in this mode:

**f = open('x.txt','r+',encoding='utf-8')**

You can then read the files line by line:

**f.readlines()**

Comment: Sir when i run this code f = open('cred.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8')

apikey = f.readlines()[1]
client_token = f.readlines()[2]
password = f.readlines()[3]
print(apikey)
print(client_token)
print(password) i'm getting error like this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nayan\PycharmProjects\Angel_Broking\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    client_token = f.readlines()[2]
IndexError: list index out of range